# window is not defined in gatsby development env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

[Getting this error when i try to use react-spring-3d-carousel in gatsby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzrdG.png)

I have checked other solution available on the platforms too but none of those worked for me.
I have set gatsby-nodejs to the following solution but it didn't work.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [{ test: /react-spring-3d-carousel/, use: loaders.null() }],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

But still its giving me the error window is not defined. I am trying to resolve this error from two weeks but none of the solutions worked for me. Help me to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ loaders, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  config.module.rules = [
    {
      test: /react-spring-3d-carousel/,
      use: loaders.null(),
    },
  ];
};
```

The approach is mostly the same but it applies to all scenarios. You can also try adding this to your condition:

```
 if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html")
```